# bootstrap 3 btn-group click event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, events, button

I am trying to figure out how to capture on click event.

```
​<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="group_period">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" for="hrb" data-value="hourly">
                                            <input type="radio" id="hrb" name="period" value="hourly"> Hourly
                                        </label> 
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" for="drb" data-value="daily">
                                            <input type="radio" id="drb" name="period" value="daily"> Daily
                                        </label> 
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" for="wrb" data-value="weekly">
                                            <input type="radio" id="wrb" name="period" value="weekly"> Weekly
                                        </label> 
                                        <label class="btn btn-default active" for="mrb" data-value="monthly">
                                            <input type="radio" id="mrb" name="period" value="monthly"> Monthly
                                        </label> 
                                    </div>
```

I have tried the following combinations, but none work.

```
 $('#group_period').change(function() {
          console.log($(this));
        });
     $('#group_period input').change(function() {
          console.log($(this));
        });

     $('#group_period label').on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)
          console.log($(this));
        });

     $('#group_period input').on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)
          console.log($(this));
        });

     $('#group_period input').on('click', function () {
            $(this).button('complete') // button text will be "finished!"
          });

     $('#group_period label').on('click', function () {
            $(this).button('complete') // button text will be "finished!"
          });


     $('#hrb').on('change', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)
          console.log($(this));
        });

    $("#hrb").bind("click", function () {
        $("#rangebox").html("Days: ");
        var select = $("#options");
        $(select).empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
            $("#options").append("<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>");
        $(select).val("3");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#hrb").on("change",function(){

   });
```

Do it like for every single buttons...

Comment: changed to all mouseup, dont work. None of the clicks works

Comment: You are fireing change event on div and I am fireing change event on radio button. If you want to do it as your way than you should fire click event on that div with id = group_period and than inside this function use change event for input id= hrb and so on. You can directly use change event on input type as I have mentioned in above example

Answer (score 0):

Just listen for all the btn-group with jquery

```
 $('#group_period input').on("click", function() {
 alert(this.id);
 });
```